# Chat app showing messages randomly when user sends a message and messages are not in proper order

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have made a basic chat app using firebase after completing my tutorial. but the app does not always show messages in order. Also, my messages are supposed to start from the bottom but they don't always do.

I have implemented firebase and firestore packages like this as I was getting error messages while mentioning the version.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  animated_text_kit: ^4.1.1
  firebase_core:
  firebase_auth:
  cloud_firestore:
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
```

In the tutorial, it's shown that you have to add .reversed after documents like the code below.

```
final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;
```

But when I tried to do the same the document property doesn't exist instead we have to use `.docs`
and I then tried to add `.reversed` after docs but still, the problem persists and messages come randomly. I also tried deleting the collection from firebase as shown in the tutorial.

below is the code to fetch the stream of messages.

```
class streamOfMessages extends StatelessWidget {
  const streamOfMessages({@required this.users,});
  final CollectionReference users;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: users.snapshots(),
        // ignore: missing_return
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData){
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            );
          }
          final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
          List<messageBubble> messageWidgets = [];
          for(var message in messages){
            final messageText = message.data()['text'];
            final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];
            final messageWidget = messageBubble(
              message: messageText,
              sender: messageSender,
              isMe: userEmail == messageSender,
            );
            messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
          }
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: messageWidgets,
              reverse: true,
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

I also tried to add a timestamp but I think I am doing something wrong. any help is much appreciated Thank you.

I have written a code in the ChatScreen dart file where I have defined everything like displaying messages and Text editing stuff.

Everything else is working fine just messages are being shown in the wrong order.

below is the whole code of the chat screen

any help is much appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
String userEmail;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'chat_screen';
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {

  final messageController = TextEditingController();
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages');
  String messageText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loggeduser();
  }

  void loggeduser(){
    try{
      final user = _auth.currentUser;
      if(user != null){
       print(user.email);
       userEmail = user.email;
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void getMessages() async {
    await for (var snapshot in _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots()){
      for (var message in snapshot.docs){
        print(message.data());
      }
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            streamOfMessages(users: users),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageController.clear();
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text' : messageText,
                        'sender' : userEmail,
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class streamOfMessages extends StatelessWidget {
  const streamOfMessages({@required this.users,});
  final CollectionReference users;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: users.snapshots(),
        // ignore: missing_return
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData){
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            );
          }
          final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
          List<messageBubble> messageWidgets = [];
          for(var message in messages){
            final messageText = message.data()['text'];
            final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];
            final messageWidget = messageBubble(
              message: messageText,
              sender: messageSender,
              isMe: userEmail == messageSender,
            );
            messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
          }
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: messageWidgets,
              reverse: true,
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}


// ignore: camel_case_types
class messageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String  message;
  final String sender;
  final bool isMe;
  messageBubble({this.message, this.sender, this.isMe, this.time});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('$sender',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize:10.0, color: Colors.black54),
          ),
          Material(
            borderRadius: isMe ? BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0)) :
            BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0),topRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
            elevation: 5.0,
            color: isMe ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,horizontal: 10.0),
                child: Text(message,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,
                    color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black54),),
              )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code doesn't specify an [order for the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) anywhere - so that would probably explain why the messages show in an undefined order.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reply I will try and specify some order.

Comment: Thank you it worked. and sorry for the late thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer you have to add a timestamp to the code and sort method to the list and problem solved.
Below is the code where changes are done.

"....." = means same code no changes needed.

```
               ............
               Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageController.clear();
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text' : messageText,
                        'sender' : userEmail,
                        'time' : DateTime.now(),   --------------> Change here
                      });
                      print(DateTime.now());
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),..............
```

another Change below

```
.............
     child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                );
              }
              final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
              List<messageBubble> messageWidgets = [];
              for(var message in messages){
                final messageText = message.data()['text'];
                final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];
                final messageTime = message.data()['time'];   ---------> added
                final messageWidget = messageBubble(
                  message: messageText,
                  sender: messageSender,
                  isMe: userEmail == messageSender,
                  time: messageTime, -----------------------------------> Add this
                );
                messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);  -----------------------------> Add bot 
                messageWidgets.sort((a , b ) => b.time.compareTo(a.time)); ------> h lines
              }
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: messageWidgets,
                  reverse: true,
                ),
              );
```

Below another change

```
.............
class messageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String  message;
  final String sender;
  final bool isMe;
  final Timestamp time;  ------------------> This is added
  messageBubble({this.message, this.sender, this.isMe, this.time}); ----> add this.time
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone seeing this in **2023-34**

You just have to add the following 2 lines in your code .

```
_firestore.collection('messages').add(
                    {
                      'text': messageText,
                      'sender': loggedInUser!.email,
                      'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),  --> Add this line
                    },
                  );
```

---

```
stream: _firestore
      .collection('messages')
      .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)     --> Add orderBy function
      .snapshots(),
```

- You don't need to apply **reversed** to the messages variable.
- Delete your collection after this and You will get the messages in a sorted
  order